# Using CSS Masonry layout, how set the height at which to break and move to a new column?

Tags: html, css, masonry

Using the below CSS Masonry layout, in Firefox, the first column shows `card 1` and `card 2` and then starts column 2 with `card 3`. But in Chrome, the first column shows `card 1`, `card 2` *and* `card 3` and then starts column 2 with `card 4`.

Setting height and max-height on the `columns` element does not work. How would I set the height at which it moves the cards to the next column so it's the same in all modern browsers (Chrome, Safari and Firefox)?

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfobotx6/

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    width: 60em;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.columns
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0em;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.card
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    background: #efefef;
    display: inline-block;
}

#card1
{

    height: 200px;
}

#card2
{

    height: 200px;
}

#card3
{

    height: 160px;
}

#card4
{

    height: 200px;
}

#card5
{

    height: 200px;
}

#card6
{

    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <link href="stylesheets/reset.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="columns">
                <div id="card1" class="card">Card 1 here</div>
                <div id="card2" class="card">Card 2 here</div>
                <div id="card3" class="card">Card 3 here</div>
                <div id="card4" class="card">Card 4 here</div>
                <div id="card5" class="card">Card 5 here</div>
                <div id="card6" class="card">Card 6 here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it to have 3 cards per column, or the 2 cards per column?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I am fine with either as long as it's under my control (CSS code that controls it) and the same in all browsers.

Comment: If you set the column height manually you can force the 3rd card to the second row, its probably not the cleanest solution but it is easy `.columns{   height: 500px;}`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith This does not work because if there are a lot of cards, then they're pushed off to the right (creating more columns) instead of adjusting the column heights. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfobotx6/2/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be unimplemented in all the browsers but is a part of the spec:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/breaks.html

The spec is for `break-before: column` to be placed on an item in the column (and using CSS, you could make this happen every **nth-item**), but none of the browsers implement this currently.

```
-webkit-column-break-before: always;
break-before: column;
```